# SQL select with WHERE clause and MAX function

Tags: sql, db2, where-clause

I have seen similar questions but none involved a number of WHERE clauses.

Is there a more efficient way to achieve the following (DB2 on z/OS), ideally without the WHERE clause repetition?

```
SELECT *
FROM     TABLE

WHERE     Value1        =   "A"
   AND    Value2        =   "B"
   AND    Tran-No       =    123
   AND    Seq-No        =  (SELECT MAX(Seq-No)

                              FROM Table

                             WHERE    Value1        =  "A"
                               AND    Value2        =  "B"
                               AND    Tran-No       =  123)
```

There are basically a number of rows matching the "WHERE" criterias and only the one with the highest Seq-No should be returned. The above method works but are there better alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you could possibly do:

```
  SELECT Seq-No
    FROM TABLE
   WHERE Value1  = "A"
     AND Value2  = "B"
     AND Tran-No = 123
ORDER BY Seq-No DESC
   LIMIT 1
```

To get the first highest `Seq-No` value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE.

```
WITH
cte
AS
(
SELECT *
       FROM "TABLE"
       WHERE "Value1" = 'A'
             AND "Value2" = 'B'
             AND "Tran-No" = 123
)
SELECT *
       FROM cte
       WHERE "Seq-No" = (SELECT max("Seq-No")
                                FROM cte);
```

Note: Do not double quote string literals (I assume `A` and `B` aren't column names). String literals are quoted with single quotes in SQL. Even if your DBMS also accepts double quotes using only single quotes is less error prone and more portable. Double quotes are for quoting identifiers with special characters, reserved/key words or to force case sensitivity. You would need that at least for the column names with `-` in them and `TABLE`. Maybe for the other identifiers too, if case matters (if not, remove it from them).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the ranking function

SELECT * FROM (
SELECT Seq-No, Value1, Value2, Trans-No, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Seq-No DESC) AS SeqRank
FROM TABLE WHERE Value1 = "A" AND Value2 = "B" and Trans-No=123
) WHERE SeqRank = 1

The inner-select statement will rank rows from 1..N based on the ORDER BY from the result of the column criteria.  There is still sorting involved however RANK() is widely supported across multiple RDBMS systems and has additional uses beyond this example.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want one row per combination of values.  That suggests `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by value1, value2, tran_no order by seq_no desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where value1 = 'A' and value2 = 'B' and trans_no = 1;
```

However, if you really want one row, no subquery is needed:

```
select t.*
from t
where value1 = 'A' and value2 = 'B' and trans_no = 1
order by seq_no
fetch first 1 row only;
```